# Building Rnn on Tensorflow for datasets of concept drift

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm building an RNN model to predict the maliciousness of malware. The dataset is of format `[malicisouness(0-1),[features*480]]`, the features are quite sparse and there are 18 months of data, sorted by month.

I am trying to input one data entry from each month and make a time-sequenced input of 18 data entries. I want the RNN to output the maliciousness of the latest month(18th month) and calculate the loss based on it.

Following is the code I am using, but I can't get the shape of inputs and tensors correctly.

```
n_steps = 18
n_inputs = 480
n_neurons = 100
n_outputs = 1
n_epochs = 20

batch_size = 50
learning_rate = 0.01

test_Y = np.empty([1065])
train_Y = np.empty([1065])

for i in range(17, len(testY), 18):
    np.append(test_Y, testY[i])
    np.append(train_Y, trainY[i])

with tf.name_scope("Variable"):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs], name = "X")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name = "Y")

    weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_steps, n_outputs]))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_outputs]))

with tf.name_scope("RNN"):
    lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = n_neurons, use_peepholes = True)
    rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
    stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons])
    stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs,name = "reshape")
    outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps])
    out = tf.matmul(outputs, weights) + bias
    out = tf.unstack(out, axis = 1)

with tf.name_scope("cost"):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y-out))

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate,name = "optimizer")
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()   

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    n = trainX.shape[0]
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        train_cost = 0
        for start, end in zip(range(0, n, batch_size*n_steps),     range(batch_size*n_steps, n, batch_size*n_steps)):
            y_start = int(start/(batch_size*n_steps))
            y_end = int(y_start + batch_size)
            X_batch, y_batch = trainX[start:end], train_Y[y_start:y_end]
            X_batch = X_batch.reshape((-1, n_steps, n_inputs))
            _, l = sess.run([training_op,loss], feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            train_cost += l

        print(epoch, "Train cost:", train_cost/(n//batch_size))
```

The output of this rnn is:
    0 Train cost: nan
    1 Train cost: nan
    2 Train cost: nan

Apparently, the input is not fed correctly, but I don't know how to make things right.